# How to read in doubles from a data file and convert them to an array using Scanner?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, double, java.util.scanner

I am basically trying to read in doubles from a data file and convert them to an array using Scanner. I have a file called "gravityV1.txt" that has a bunch of positive doubles in it:

> 3.76
>
> 8.87
>
> 1.0
>
> 3.71
>
> 24.92
>
> 10.44
>
> 8.87
>
> 11.15
>
> 0.58

#### Other Information:

Below is most of my Source Code for a program that calculates your weight on each planet in the solar system(including Pluto). It scans a file called "gravityV1.txt", which includes the list of doubles aforementioned. Then it is supposed to read the txt file into an array, calculate the weight (in pounds) for each planet, and display the info in a table.

#### A Few More Things

This program uses multiple methods (in addition to the main), and if I have written anything regarding method calling incorrectly, please call me out!

In this case, the array needs to be long enough for each of the surface gravity measurements of the 9 planets to fit, but how would you denote the array if one did not know long one's array needed to be?

#### But Most Importantly...

I have done *extensive* research on this problem, and I still have run into issues. This Source Code below does not compile because of a "possible loss of precision" error. The error message also says: "required: int; found double".

Can someone please show me why this error occurs and also
how to read this file and make it into an array called gravityData?

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class WeightOnPlanetsV1
  {
   
    public static void printHeadings( )  //notice method is void, nothing returned
    {
      System.out.printf("%37s\n","My Weight on the Planets");
      System.out.println();
      System.out.printf("%s%20s%20s\n","Planet","Gravity","Weight(lbs)");
      System.out.println("==============================================");
    }

    public static double [] loadGravityData( ) throws IOException
    {
      Scanner myFileScanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("gravity1.txt"));
      int count = 0;  
      double [] gravityData = new double[myFileScanner.nextDouble()];
         for(int i = 0; i < gravityData.length; i++)
         {
            gravityData[i] = myFileScanner.nextDouble();
         }
      myFileScanner.close();
      return gravityData;
    }
 
    public static double [] calculateWeight() throws IOException
    {
        loadGravityData( );
        double [] gravityData = new double[10];
        double [] mass = new double [9];
        double [] weight = new double [9];
        
        int count = 0;
          for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
          {
            mass[count] = ((140.0 * 433.59237) / gravityData[count]);  //Calculates mass based on planet's gravity
            weight[count] = (mass[count] * gravityData[count]) / 10;   // calculates weight based on mass, division by 10 is for some physics reason I believe
            count++;
          }
        
       return weight;
    }    
 

// Starts the MAIN! 
   public static void main(String[ ] args) throws IOException
   {
    double [] gravityData = new double [9];
    printHeadings();
    String [] planets = {"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune", "Pluto"};           
    
    calculateWeight();
    double [] weight = calculateWeight();           
       
    for(int y = 0; y < 9 ; y++)
       {
           System.out.printf("%-11s", planets[y]);     
           System.out.printf("%13.2f", gravityData[y]); 
           System.out.printf("%20.2f\n",weight[y]);
       }
   
  } // end main
```

I welcome any help at all! **Thank you!**

## Edit:

Alright this is what i have now for the loadGravityData method:

```
{
    Scanner myFileScanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("gravity1.txt"));
  int count = 0;  
  double [] gravityData = new double[myFileScanner.nextInt()];
     for(int i = 0; i < gravityData.length; i++)
     {
        gravityData[i] = myFileScanner.nextDouble();
     }
  myFileScanner.close();
  return gravityData;
}
```

And I get "Main.java:20: error: cannot return a value from method whose result type is void" ??

Comment: Your research/question is unfocused, but maybe it got late. That particular compiler error is easy to fix, because you are giving it a `double` for the length of an array, which expects an integer. So readInt if that's what you expect first.

Comment: @clwhisk Yes, unfortunately it has gotten quite late, and my question _is_ unfocused, and I apologize for that. I think what you commented would help a lot though. Would you mind showing me how exactly you mean to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write following code to convert file data to array. You need add all data to `List`, because you do not know the size of array, than convert `List` to array.

```
public static double [] loadGravityData( ) throws IOException
{
 Scanner sc=new Scanner(new File("gravity1.txt"));
    List<Double> arr=new ArrayList<>();
    while(sc.hasNext()){
        arr.add(sc.nextDouble());
    }
    double doubleArr[]=new double[arr.size()];
    for (int i=0;i< arr.size();i++) {
        doubleArr[i]=arr.get(i);
    }
  return   doubleArr;
}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks @Masud ! I tried that, exactly as you have it, but it gave me a different error: "cannot find symbol - class List". Also, in the method call, is "Double" supposed to be capitalized? Sorry, I am quite a greenhorn programmer!

Comment: Just wanted to point out that this is also possible without using a `List`. The user could create two arrays. One with a massive length size that stores input and then another that could copy all the necessary data from the massive length array into a smaller more precise array which would be much more easier to manipulate and work with versus a `List`.

Comment: @ReneaS. You need to import List from java.util.List package.

Comment: @Masud Got it! And...now it can't find symbol "class ArrayList"?

Comment: @Tdorno thanks for your idea. But that needs redundant code and loop. Java always recommended to use its library.

Comment: @ReneaS. You also need to import ArrayList.

Comment: @Masud I see, thank you! So now why does it say error "incompatible types" for this line: return (Double[]) arr.toArray();

Comment: @Masud It compiles (hooray!) but when I run the program I get a Stack Overflow Error. In my class, we have not learned to use Objects in our programs, so I think your solution is a little over my head... Thank you for all your help.

Comment: @Masud Through redundancy we learn different ways to optimize our code. You made it sound as if `List` is the OP's only option to approach this. If this is infact for some sort of school homework/project odds are they haven't learned about `Lists` at all so from a professor's POV I'm sure they would be quite curious as to why one of their students is using something they haven't learned. If this is not for school then just disregard that last sentence =D.

Comment: @Tdorno Yeah, it is for AP Computer Science A. But I only have it as an online class, so I really don't have a teacher. (Although my long-distance teacher is nice about trying to help.) It is very challenging to learn without lectures!

Answer (score 0):

`double [] gravityData = new double[myFileScanner.nextDouble()];`

Presumably the first entry in the file is `99` not `2.53`, so you can simply

`double [] gravityData = new double[myFileScanner.nextInt()];`

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean now. Thanks! And well, the first entry in the file **is** 2.53. Is there something in my code that is leading you to see differently(that could be part of my problem)? Or will having that be the first entry not change anything? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Actually compiling the code now results in an error: "java.util.InputMismatchExecption: null (in java.util.Scanner)" What does this mean? @clwhisk

Comment: @ReneaS. It looked like you thought the first entry was the number of data points. If not, Masud's answer is obviously more helpful.